# How do I write a generic function that takes a Number or some alphabets and display that in 7- bit segment display.?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to write a Digital Clock application in which I have a 7- bit segment display. I want to write a generic code for displaying all the input. I have a CGPath in which I have 1 line for  each segment.
Now, how would I write a generic function for the above description?
Any help with some logic or code will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simplest would be a look-up table.  You could do it with ten bytes.  Assign one bit in the bytes to each segment.  Pre-load the table with the hex values necessary to set the bits.  Index the table with your digit 0-9.  If you want to have additional combinations of segments then make the table larger -- typically these are set up to display an additional 6 "characters" (eg, A, b, C, d, E, and F), making the table conveniently 16 long.

But, for extra credit, do it with NAND gates.

Comment: That was a bit of a joke.  NAND gates are, of course, primitive digital circuits -- the building blocks of all digital devices.  You can design the basic circuit you'd need fairly easily (simple Boolean logic), but implementing it would require you to do some actually wiring.  (And fitting those wires into an iPhone would be a trick.)

Comment: (But if this is a class assignment, it might impress your instructor if you DID turn in a design in NAND logic (in addition to the software solution to the problem, of course).  While it may seem scary to the uninitiated, basic logic circuit design is really quite simple if you comprehend Boolean algebra reasonably well.  And drawing out the design is fairly easy with pencil and paper (plus there may be some tools on the web to do the drawing for you).)